# Where is Filters folder in ASP .NET MVC 5 solution known from MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I follow Scott Allen's tutorial through MVC 4. He talks about InitializeSimpleMembershipAttributes file inside Filters folder. I can't find any of it in my solution. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Filters folder in MVC5.  The Filters folder is there for the SimpleMembership filters that were introduced in MVC4.  MVC5 does not use SImpleMembership, but uses ASP.NET Identity which does not have those filters, thus no filter folder is present.

Comment: mvc 5 uses different approach for membership?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - It doesn't use membership at all.  It uses ASP.NET Identity, which is a claims based identity management solution.  Although you can still use the older Membership system if you want to.. you'll have to set it up manually.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Now I found out hat everything I watched about Authorization is outdated. Luckily there is Scott Allen's video tutorial about Identity.

Comment: i also never used Microsoft membership, in my cases i already had database so i had to use custom login

Comment: You may want to check Scott Allen MVC 5 Fundamental course as well.  It gives details information about what's new MVC 5.  MVC 4 course is a pre-requisite of it, though.